# IdentityServer4 with Asp.Net Identity and External Authentication fails to sign out

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the asp.net identity quickstart:
   https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity

2.Add google authentication nuget package

3. Configure Google Authentication:

3a. In Startup.cs, ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(x=> { x.Cookies.ExternalCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "Google"; })
```

3b. In Startup.cs, Configure method:

```
app.UseIdentity();
   app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
        AutomaticChallenge = false
    });

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
        SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
        ClientId = "your client id",
        ClientSecret = "your client secret"
    });
```

Launch identity server and the mvc client. You should be able to login with google and register. Click the Logout button and you get the below error:

```
Specified method is not supported.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler1.HandleSignOutAsync(SignOutContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler1.d__63.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.d__14.MoveNext()
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong? Github issue here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/530